# I have used FlowListView but it's not working properly in iOS?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have created a sample for gallery view. For that i have used the flowlistview nuget. It's working fine in Android but in iOS it shows a weird arrow in grid. Any idea?

**UserPhotos.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<ContentPage
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:flv="clr-namespace:DLToolkit.Forms.Controls;assembly=DLToolkit.Forms.Controls.FlowListView"
    x:Class="MyApp.UserPhotos"
    Title="Photos">

    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout Padding="10" Margin="5">
            <flv:FlowListView 
                HasUnevenRows="True"
                FlowColumnCount="2"
                FlowItemTappedCommand="{Binding ItemTappedCommand}"
                SeparatorVisibility="Default"
                FlowItemsSource="{Binding userAlbumsList}">

                <flv:FlowListView.FlowColumnTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Frame x:Name="itemTemp"
                               Margin="5"
                               CornerRadius="5"
                               BackgroundColor="#5d6d20"
                               HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                               VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                            <StackLayout Padding="0,8,0,8"
                                         VerticalOptions="Center"
                                         HorizontalOptions="Center">
                                <Image Aspect="AspectFit"
                                       HeightRequest="60"
                                       WidthRequest="60"
                                       Source="album.png"
                                       HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                       VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
                            </StackLayout>
                        </Frame>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </flv:FlowListView.FlowColumnTemplate>

            </flv:FlowListView>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>

</ContentPage>
```

**[image: Output:]**

**[image]**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use **CustomRenderer** to set the **Accessory** of the cell in iOS .

```
using MyApp.iOS;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(ViewCell), typeof(StandardViewCellRenderer))]
namespace MyApp.iOS
{
    public class StandardViewCellRenderer : ViewCellRenderer
    {

        public override UIKit.UITableViewCell GetCell(Cell item, UIKit.UITableViewCell reusableCell, UIKit.UITableView tv)
        {
            var cell = base.GetCell(item, reusableCell, tv);
            switch (item.StyleId)
            {
                case "none":
                    cell.SelectionStyle = UIKit.UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None;
                    break;
                case "checkmark":
                    cell.Accessory = UIKit.UITableViewCellAccessory.Checkmark;
                    break;
                case "detail-button":
                    cell.Accessory = UIKit.UITableViewCellAccessory.DetailButton;
                    break;
                case "detail-disclosure-button":
                    cell.Accessory = UIKit.UITableViewCellAccessory.DetailDisclosureButton;
                    break;
                case "disclosure":
                default:
                    cell.Accessory = UIKit.UITableViewCellAccessory.None;
                    break;
            }
            return cell;


        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Check my update answer , in your sample , set `cell.Accessory = UIKit.UITableViewCellAccessory.None;`  in default .

Comment: There are two cell renderer in your iOS project , delete one of them (CellRenderer in Renderer folder ) . And delete the folder bin and obj both in share project and iOS project , then clean and rebuild it .

Comment: Now i'm getting this error Method not found: void .ResourceLoadingQuery.set_Instance(object)

Comment: Make sure all version of Xamarin.forms in share project and iOS/Android are up to date .

Comment: I used static source and it works fine whether use custom renderer or not . I test it on iOS simulator 13.2 . You could download it and test .https://github.com/luczha/FlowListView_Sample

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204839/discussion-between-lucas-zhang-msft-and-divyesh-008).